# Community Rejected Edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

[Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) rejected the following edit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62814

I really think this answer should change because it typesets text in math mode. (There also other improvements.)

How do I convince [Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)?

Comment: As far as I understand, this edit was rejected only because it conflicted with a subsequent edit, community didn't deem your edit undesirable in any way. I guess that the proper course of action is to resubmit the edit.

Comment: @T.Verron Thanks. I notice egreg made an edit.

Answer (score 8):

Exactly as T. Verron says, your edit was rejected because it was conflicting with another edit by the OP, which overpowers suggested edits.

What is strange, IMHO, that the OP's edit is actually verbatim the same as your edit.
Therefore another possibility is that the OP actually hit "Reject and Edit" in the review. However, his edit review is not in the system, which should mean that he didn't act on your review. But who knows.